# Flipping a card in React

Tags: reactjs, css-animations, css-transitions, css-transforms, framer-motion

I have this component that works, but I want to add the effect of the text staying on the card while it is rotating. Right now when you click on the card, the text disappears, the card rotates, then the text for the back of the card appears. But I want the text to transition with the flip. I have tried using a transform property, but nothing is working. I would appreciate some ideas. Thank you so much!

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Tilt from "react-tilt";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { services } from "../constants";
import { fadeIn, textVariant } from "../utils/motion";
import { SectionWrapper } from "../hoc";

const ServiceCard = ({ index, title, icon, services_detail }) => {
  const [cardFlipped, setCardFlipped] = useState(false);

  const flipCard = () => {
    setCardFlipped(!cardFlipped);
  };

  return (
    <Tilt
      options={{ reverse: true, reset: false }}
      className="xs:w-[250px] w-full"
    >
      <motion.div
        variants={fadeIn("left", "spring", index * 0.5, 0.75)}
        className="w-full green-pink-gradient p-[1px] rounded-[20px] shadow-card"
      >
        <motion.div
          onClick={flipCard}
          style={{
            perspective: "1000px",
            cursor: "pointer",
            transformStyle: "preserve-3d",
            rotateY: cardFlipped ? 180 : 0,
          }}
          animate={{ rotateY: cardFlipped ? 180 : 0 }}
          transition={{ duration: 0.8 }}
          initial={{ rotateY: 0 }}
          className="bg-tertiary rounded-[20px] py-5 px-12 min-h-[280px] flex justify-evenly items-center flex-col"
        >
          {/* Front of the card */}
          <motion.img
            src={icon}
            alt="web-development"
            className="w-16 h-16 object-contain"
            style={{
              rotateY: cardFlipped ? "180deg" : "0deg",
              backfaceVisibility: "hidden",
              position: "relative",
              visibility: cardFlipped ? "hidden" : "visible",
            }}
          />
          <motion.h3
            className="text-white text-[20px] font-bold text-center"
            style={{
              rotateY: cardFlipped ? "180deg" : "0deg",
              backfaceVisibility: "hidden",
              position: "relative",
              visibility: cardFlipped ? "hidden" : "visible",
            }}
          >
            {title}
          </motion.h3>
          {/* Back of the card */}
          <motion.div
            style={{
              position: "absolute",
              top: 0,
              left: 0,
              width: "100%",
              height: "100%",
              transform: `rotateY(${cardFlipped ? 180 : 0}deg)`,
              backfaceVisibility: "hidden",
            }}
          >
            {services_detail.map((detail, index) => (
              <div key={index} style={{ opacity: cardFlipped ? 1 : 0 }}>
                {detail}
              </div>
            ))}
          </motion.div>
        </motion.div>
      </motion.div>
    </Tilt>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you make an example here? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new